# typescript: named function within class

Tags: typescript

Below typescript code

```
class MyClass{
     test1 = function(){    
     }       
     test2(){   
     }
}
```

generates

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.test1 = function () {
        };
    }
    MyClass.prototype.test2 = function () {
    };
    return MyClass;
})();
```

I used to have javascript named function within a module, normally for recursion etc. Is it possible to have a function, **within a class**, assigned to a variable, or a named function which is not part of prototype or `this`. something like `test3` and `test4` below.

```
    var MyClass = (function () {
        function test3(){    
        }  
        var test4 = function(){     
        }
        function MyClass() {
            this.test1 = function () {
                //test3 and test4 are accessible here..
            };
        }
        MyClass.prototype.test2 = function () {
        };
        return MyClass;
    })();
```

Comment: What do you mean, for recursion? Maybe a closure?

Comment: like, `recur(pid){ ... ;...; _.each(ch, (c) => {...; recur(c.Id)}} ;` . I thought it is neater not to add recur to prototype, though it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the static keyword prior to the function, and it will be bound to the function constructor only, not the prototype or this.  There is no way to make it completely hidden within the closure.

TypeScript

```
class MyClass{
    static test1 = function(){    
    }       
    test2(){
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyClass.prototype.test2 = function () {
    };
    MyClass.test1 = function () {
    };
    return MyClass;
})();
```

Comment: Good answer +1. You can additionally mark it as private and typescript will prevent you from using it externally `private static test1 = function(){` (not really private but it is sufficient if you use TS)